# display a map in html

Tags: javascript, html

how to use map in html and then also leave some mark on it  actually I am creating a app for a business community I want to show their stores location on map can you tell me how 
it will be your most kindness

Comment: learn to use google map

Comment: check this link You may get basic idea on google map https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/google_maps_intro.asp

Comment: thank you very much nair athul

Comment: Learn to search!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the best option for you is to use the "Google Maps Embed API" that allows you to add a Google Map to your site without writing code or quota limits.

Google has step by step instructions available here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/

Answer (score 1):

you haven't specified thaton which platform you are working.

So you can get basic concept for 'google map in html' here on w3school :

https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/google_maps_basic.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_googlemaps.asp

Hope it will helpfull